# Laravel one-to-many relationship returns null

Tags: database, null, relationship, one-to-many, laravel

So here's what i have set up. I have two tables; `users` and `todos`. Every user can have multiple "todos".

Here's what the tables look like:

Users:
[image]

Todos:
[image]

And the models:

```
class User extends Eloquent 
{
    public function todo() {
        $this->has_many('todo');
    }
}
```

And...

```
class Todo extends Eloquent 
{
    public function user() {
        $this->belongs_to('user');
    }
}
```

Note that i already have a "todo" attached to the user in the database. So, with that said, should i not be able to do the following:

```
$user = User::find(1)->todo;
```

To get the todo's for that user? I'm currently getting Null when `dd()`-ing it:

```
array(1) {
  ["todo"]=>
  NULL
}
```

So, any ideas? I tried removing `belongs_to()` from the Todo's model, because it shouldn't be needed right? Either way it makes no difference. Am i missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the relation objects, e.g.

```
class User extends Eloquent 
{
    public function todos() {
        return $this->has_many('Todo');
    }
}
```

Also note that relations that return an array (e.g. has_many, has_many_and_belongs_to) are typically named plural, so 'todos' versus 'todo.

Comment: Wow, yeah that's embarassing! Thanks :)